# AC Phase Shifter for LED lamps

Tags: led, home-electronics

All the LED lamps that are available locally have noticeable flicker, and I have the same problem with the lamps that I've ordered online. **Is there any device that could phase-shift 220 V 50 Hz AC home electricity so that I could run two LED bulbs out of phase from each other?**

I have read that [stadium lighting uses three 120-degree phases](http://www.archlighting.com/technology/leds-fighting-flicker_o) to handle flicker. I would thus prefer such a system for my LED lamps, but if a device with two 180-degrees phasing exists I would be happy with that as well.

Comment: A frequency doubler is a fairly straightforward electronic circuit, but I'm not aware of anyone who makes one for consumer use.